# Set build number for Jenkins workflow (pipeline) builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am migrating  jenkins-workflow job to new template based workflow job.  Because the build number is used as part of the version of build artifacts the workflow produces I have to start build number of the new workflow with a number greater than the old workflow.  Unfortunately 'Next Build Number' plugin does not work with workflow pipeline.

Anybody knows a good way do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try running below script in Jenkins Script Console.. Change "workFlow" to your Jobname

```
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem("workFlow")
job.nextBuildNumber = 10
job.saveNextBuildNumber()
```

Comment: This code snippet does not write the new build number to the `nextBuildNumber` file. Due to this, if you (gracefully) restart Jenkins and then trigger a build, it ends up using whatever build number was present in the `nextBuildNumber` file (and not the one specified in the above snippet). Using `job.saveNextBuildNumber()` instead of `job.save()` addresses this issue.

Answer (score 19):

Or, you could add a snippet like this to your Pipeline/Workflow job DSL script (aka [Jenkinsfile](https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow)):

```
offset = 5
currentBuild.displayName = "#" + (currentBuild.number + offset)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Note this is cosmetic only --doesn't change the _actual_ build number.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately the methods listed above didn't work for me when using folders. I resorted to the following in the Jenkins script console:

```
job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName("BSKAzureConversion-Jobs/master", Job.class)
job.nextBuildNumber = 92
job.save()
```

Comment: If using `job.saveNextBuildNumber()` for line 3, this worked for my multi-branch pipeline.

Comment: To find your job name from the multi-branch pipeline, run this:

`def jobs = Jenkins.getInstance().getAllItems(); println(jobs)`


And then, as @DavidV described above:

`def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("YourTeam/your_project/features%2Fbranchname"); job.nextBuildNumber = 301; job.saveNextBuildNumber();`

Comment: this alternative worked for me. thanks

I added a println to check after a change
def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName("package/build-package", Job.class)

println(job.nextBuildNumber)

job.nextBuildNumber = 254
println(job.nextBuildNumber)
job.saveNextBuildNumber()

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

- Jenkins Jobs and Folders are not serializable. Need to use `@NonCPS`
- Disable Groovy Sandbox, as globals like `Jenkins.instance` are not accessible otherwise
- `Jenkins.instance.getItem()` won't work well with folders. Use `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName` against the `env.JOB_NAME`
- Setting `job.nextBuildNumber` will take effect subsequent build, so go ahead and kick off the next one
- Make sure you return out of your pipeline so the initiating build doesn't continue with bad build number

Code:

```
@NonCPS
def updateBuildNumber(build_number) {
  def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME, Job.class)
  job.nextBuildNumber = build_number
  job.saveNextBuildNumber()
  build env.JOB_NAME
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @Jayan's answer and modified it to support getting a branch from that workflow because `getItem("workflow/job/mybranch")` did not work

```
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem("workFlow").getItemByBranchName("mybranch")
job.nextBuildNumber = 10
job.saveNextBuildNumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way of doing this by using 'jenkins-cli'.  It works for locked down installations where access to script console is not available (Cloudbees Enterprise Jenkins)

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar   -s https://instanceURL/ \
          set-next-build-number workflow-name  33
```